# adding parameters to overridden method E_STRICT observation

Tags: php, oop, coding-style

It appears (PHP 5.3) that if you are overriding a class method, <del>it is okay to</del> you can add additional parameters, as long as they have default values.

For example, consider the class:

```
class test1 {
  public function stuff() {
    echo "Hi";
  }
}
```

The following class extends "test1" and will produce an E_STRICT warning.

```
class test2 extends test1 {
  public function stuff($name) {
    echo "Hi $name";
  }
}
```

But, the following does not produce an E_STRICT warning.

```
class test3 extends test1 {
  public function stuff($name = "") {
    echo "Hi $name";
  }
}
```

While class "test3" doesn't produce an E_STRICT warning, I have been under the impression that PHP does not allow method signatures to be <del>overloaded</del> overridden. So, I have to ask. Is my observation a bug/flaw or actually <del>correct</del> intended behavior?

Further, if a *default argument parameter* is okay, why is a *non-default argument parameter* not okay?

Comment: i have error_reporting(E_ALL) set and cannot reproduce the E_STRICT erorr. can you post the error that you are seeing? Also, this is not a case of 'overloading', it is 'overwriting'.

Comment: No, it's not Ok. Read about [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) And PHP allows to do it.

Comment: @helloandre, E_STRICT not included in E_ALL. To turn on E_STRICT notices, set `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

Comment: @helloandre and E_STRICT isn't generated for this case :)

Comment: I am not getting any error belongs to E_STRICT.I am getting outputs.

Answer (score 5):

If you add a non-defaulted parameter to an overridden method, the subclass no longer satisfies the contract defined by the superclass.  You cannot correctly call test2->stuff(), because this method now expects a parameter - but the superclass says you should be able to call it without one.  Hence the E_STRICT warning.

If you add a defaulted parameter though, you can still call test3->stuff() (from your example) - as the superclass expects - and so the contract is not broken.  In fact, by adding the optional parameter, you have simply extended it.

Answer (score -2):

This is not a bug and is acceptable PHP programming practise.

Please note that multiple overrides can cause `programmer headaches` though and should be avoided where possible.

Alternatively I usually either have a single extended class to override per class or just overload a class method within the actual class itself.