# Overriding cake methods in E_STRICT

Tags: php, cakephp, methods, cakephp-2.0

Whats the best practice in overriding methods?
Especially if we need to add another param?

This is not E_STRICT compliant (adding $soft as second param):

```
public function delete($id, $soft = false, $cascade = true) {
    if ($soft) {
        return $this->_softDelete();
    }
    return parent::delete($id, $cascade);
}
```

Resulting in:

```
Declaration of Conversation::delete() should be compatible with that of Model::delete()
```

I know that one shoudn't override methods this way ([adding-parameters-to-overriden-method-e-strict-observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699949/adding-parameters-to-overriden-method-e-strict-observation)).

but If one has to, how would one proceed? (without having to remove E_STRICT)
The basic idea was to intercept the normal delete calls without having to rewrite all occurrences of this model method call.

Comment: Did you try use `beforeDelete` method in AppModel? Maybe it's a good alternative to override the core `delete()`.

Comment: well, my question is more a generic one (the above is only a concrete use case as example). there are lots of other places in the code where this problem occurs in E_STRICT mode. So I will have to address all of them somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either `E_STRICT` compatibility, or modyfing function signatures. You can't have both.

The solution is usually to use composition instead of inheritance, that is to wrap the object which behaviout you'd like to modify within a new class with different signatures.