# Overriding controller Synfony2 with a new parameter in a function

Tags: symfony

I'm overriding the SecurityController from FOSUserBundle.
I try to persist some data after the login but for that I need to add the "Request $request" parameter to the function  protected function renderLogin but I get the following error:

Runtime Notice: Declaration of Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Controller\SecurityController::renderLogin() should be compatible with FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::renderLogin(array $data)

Here is my code:

```
 /**
     * Renders the login template with the given parameters. Overwrite this function in
     * an extended controller to provide additional data for the login template.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function renderLogin(array $data, Request $request)
    {
        function is_session_started()
            {
                if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
                    if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
                        return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
                    } else {
                        return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
                    }
                }
                return FALSE;
            }


            if (is_session_started() == TRUE)
                {
                    $session = $request->getSession();
                    $content = $session->get('result');
                    $idQuery = $session->get('query_id');
                    $authorId = $this->getUser()->getId();

                    $biblio = new Biblio;
                    $biblio->setAuthorId($authorId);
                    $biblio->setContent($content);
                    $biblio->setQueryId($idQuery);
                    $biblio->setDate(new \DateTime());
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->persist($biblio);
                    $em->flush();

                    $session->clear();

                    $response = $this->forward('BiblishareBundle:Profile:show');

                    return $response;
                }
            else
                {
                    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', $data);
                }

    }
```

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to listen for the login event instead.

It is described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11180531/982075 and can be applied to FOSUserBundle by using the `fos_user.security.interactive_login` event.

That way you don't have to override the SecurityController from FOSUserBundle yet you can persist data after login.

Answer (score 0):

When you override method with different set of parameters it will produce E_STRICT error - this is php specific and Symfony is just following standards. So it seems you need to solve your problem differently. How about using:

```
$request = $this->getRequest()
```

in your method (I assume base class of your controller is Symfony's `Controller`)

Check these for more info:

[PHP: "Declaration of ... should be compatible with that of ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158243/php-declaration-of-should-be-compatible-with-that-of)

[adding parameters to overridden method E_STRICT observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699949/adding-parameters-to-overriden-method-e-strict-observation)

[Why is overriding method parameters a violation of strict standards in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423494/why-is-overriding-method-parameters-a-violation-of-strict-standards-in-php)

NOTE: messy code you have there. You can check if session is started by using `$this->get('session')->isStarted()`

Comment: Thank you it works... By the way do you know which controller is validating the login form?

Comment: $this->getRequest() is deprecated and to be removed in Symfony3.